# Ngx-datatable draggable row

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am trying to implement drag&drop functionality on ngx-datatable rows.

As mentioned in this open request on Github https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/411, there is a custom directive I can add to achieve this.
However, all the plunkers provided show multiple issues in the console when I tried to open them.

I've created a working sample here https://codesandbox.io/s/121n85o33, but the feature is not working properly. If you play around, you can see the rows are dropped without order. 
It will be great if someone can point me in the right direction to fix the problem.

Comment: Hey @Ardenne, Have you found a solution. Please let me in if you have. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @TorabShaikh. Unfortunately, I stopped working on this issue a couple of months ago. I think someone else is working on it on the GitHub page. You should try there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the slice call in onDrop in your AppComponent.ts :

```
onDrop(event) {
  console.log("onDrop", event);
  // ngx-datatable recommends you force change detection
  //let newData = event.slice();

  // OR let this.data = [...event]
  this.rows = event;
  console.log("update", this.rows);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have updated my repo. 
Unfortunately, the answer came a little late for my task, but I will keep the sample available for others.

Comment: @Ardenne The sample seems to be offline - could you make it available again please?

Comment: I am trying to use this. But when building the app, getting these errors. `dragula-extended.directive.ts(107,7): error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2. dragula-extended.directive.ts(111,54): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(groupName?: string) => Observable<{ name: string; el: Element; source: Element; }>'. dragula-extended.directive.ts(114,54): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(groupName?: string) => Observable<{ name: string; el: Element; target: Element; source: Element;...'.` What could be the issue?

Comment: "Expected 1 arguments, but got 2" this error is because of the latest changes in ng2-dragula library.